# Как оптимизировать такое регулярное выражение?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь разобрать `html` тег (строку текста, похожую на html тег) на составные части.

Пример тега: `<div class="test" data-status="false">`

Мое регулярное выражение:

```
<([a-z]+)(?:\s*)(?:(class)="(.*?)")(?:\s*)(?:(data-.*)="(.*?)").*>
```

Вопросы:

1. Учитывая, что все идет по шаблону (например атрибуты id|class|data-), то как лучше оптимизировать|улучшить регулярное выражение? Возможно 2 раза "искать, но не запоминать пробел" не нужно...
2. Имеется ли возможность помещать содержимое атрибутов сразу в дополнительный массив, который следует сразу за родительским атрибутом? Например было: `{'class', 'vasya petya'}`, стало: `{'class': {vasya petya}}`.
   На настоящий момент, произвожу данную операцию в дополнительном цикле.

UPD: это не html тег, а строка текста похожая на него. Изучаю регулярные выражения и для примера взял подобного рода задачу. То, что для парсинга html лучше использовать другие инструменты - вкурсе.

Comment: Зачем вы парсите html с помощью регулярного выражения? Чего в итоге хотите добиться?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Если строка отличается от валидного html (или xml) только отсутствием закрывающего тэга, то многие xml-парсеры такие xml вполне умеют понимать. Если строка отличается чем-то еще, то чем?

Comment: @Yaant представьте, что в примере не html тег, а просто набор слов. html тег был взят лишь для примера в качестве обучения. Вопрос стоит лишь в обучение регуляркам, а не обучению парсингу html.

Comment: какой результат ожидается? должна ли регулярка работать независимо от порядка атрибутов?

Comment: @Grundy нет, не должна. С другой стороны хотелось бы увидеть оба варианта, для наглядности.

Comment: как эта регулярка применяется к строке?

Comment: @Grundy для наглядности, использую вывод в консоль + match() `console.log('<div class="test" data-status="false">'.match(/<([a-z]+)(?:\s*)(?:(class)="(.*?)")(?:\s*)(?:(data-.*)="(.*?)").*>/m));`

Comment: @And интересный вариант, пишите как ответ - отмечу решением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите, чтобы и `class=""`, `class = ' '` были разные символы, одинарная или двойная кавычка, а также пробел перед = может быть, а может не быть 
Можно попробовать следующее выражение:

```
<([a-z]*)\s(class)\s?=\s?\S([^"\']*)\S\s(data(?:-\S*)?)\s?=\s?\S([^"\']*)\S>
```